# How to determine UDP socket buffer size in C#?

Tags: c#, udp, buffer

I'll be sending UDP packets (1500 bytes) of ECG data continuously for up to 5 minutes. What is a safe `socket.ReceiveBufferSize` I could use? I'll be filtering this data and plotting the data as it comes in. I want to prevent any buffer issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
int packetSize = 1500; // as stated in the question
int safeBufferSize = maxPacketsPerSec * packetSize * howManySecondsToBuffer;
```

Figure out or estimate your value for `maxPacketsPerSec`, choose a safe/generous value for `howManySecondsToBuffer`, something in the range of, say, 5 (to at least weather even the worst garbage collection pauses) to 60 (or even the full 300 seconds if you are completely paranoid), and then do the math.

**More important though: Heave the bytes out of the socket receive buffer as fast as you can**, hand them over to some queue which is processed by some other thread, or multiple threads, if need be. That way your in-app queue will buffer as much as you have RAM, and your `Socket.ReceiveBufferSize` value will become less important.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent any issues you need to use TCP.
In case you are using udp you are posibly loss data or get wrong sequence of packets.

Comment: but it depends what he needs to do, he might not need tcp for his use case.

Comment: Actually, he 'want to prevent ANY buffer issues'. So it my subjective understanding of this question. Of course he can use udp, add packet number, control sum checking and packet resending. If sombody have another vision of 'buffer issues' please let me know, instead of downvoting.